# Is there a way to purge all content and maintain settings?

Tags: mysql, database, maintenance

I need to purge huge amount of data from J but maintain settings / modules etc.

I've tried to write cli tool to clean up tables using correct models, but it is taking too much time. Is there a simple way?

Ideally I would reinstall J and import settings but is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suggest, it may be quickest and simplest to create a new Joomla install and transfer over the things you wish to keep.

SP Transfer http://www.kainotomo.com/products/sp-transfer or similar can help with this and you can be quite selective about what you want transferred (e.g. users, content, menus, modules etc).

You'd also need to reinstall any third party extensions which may or may not be straightforward depending on what is installed.

Comment: Well, it turned out to be a waste of time. diff/merging db caused more problems down the road, and the source of all the issues is assets table - basically impossible to manually track the changes there and merge correctly.

Comment: That plugin looks promising though.